# I am making a turret but it won't shoot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a turret that shoots a bullet at a set rate, but when the timer is done it doesn't spawn a new bullet even though it doesn't say i have any errors. the bullet has a simple script where it moves at a set speed either left or right, and gets destroyed on impact with an object. the turret does not have a collider right now so I know that's not the problem.

Here is the code for shooting:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class TurretShoot : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject bullet;
        public int bullet_rate = 10;
        public int timer;
        public Transform SpawnPoint;

        void Start()
        {
            timer = bullet_rate * 10;
        }
    
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if (timer == 0)
            {
                Instantiate(bullet, SpawnPoint.transform);
                timer = bullet_rate * 10;
            }
            else
            {
                timer -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the bullet code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int moveDirection;
    public int moveSpeed;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        this.transform.position += new Vector3(moveDirection * moveSpeed, 0, 0);
    }

    void onCollisionEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.GetComponent<Collider>().name != "turret_top")
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the inspector for the turret:

[image]

Comment: Please make sure that this MonoBehavuour is in your GameObject on the scene, without more context I do not see where the issue might come from

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak would the bullet being a prefab break it?

Comment: No, bullets being prefab do not change anything.
I would add `Debug.Log` to the instantiate method. I think you might have overlapping colliders that destroy bullets immidietely.

Comment: Did you try running it in debug mode and confirm it does not appear in the object hierarchy, or if it does, double clicking on the bullet in the scene editor to ensure it spawns at the expected location?

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak i do not have a collider on the turret so i dont know what it would be colliding with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what is happening is it get's destroyed when it spawns.

> I don't have a collider on the turret

You aren't instantiating it at the turrent. You are simply setting the parent when you are instantiating it:

```
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);
```

Meaning it is probally spawning at `Vector3.Zero` and instantly gets de-spawn.
Rather use the overload method of:

```
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);
```

That way you are spawning it the location you want. This is how you would go about it:

```
var bulletObj = Instantiate(bullet, SpawnPoint.transform.position, Quaternion.Identity);
bulletObj.transform.parent = SpawnPoint.transform;
timer = bullet_rate * 10;
```